# Recursive subtraction function

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make this function, that will take 2 arguments, Double and list of doubles.
So idea is to subract from Double, all of the list values.

Example

I'm using Integers in this example for convenience.

This would print 4

```
f = do
  let a = 10
  let b = [1,2,3]
  let c = f2 a b
  print c
```

This will subtract with first value from list, but how to do it all?

```
f2 0 _      = 0
f2 x []     = x
f2 x (y:ys) = x - y
```

This will subtract with number 1, probably just taking how many lists there are.

```
f3 0 _      = 0
f3 x []     = x
f3 x (y:ys) = x - f3 (x-y) ys
```

I have tryed bunch of different ways to make it work, but i just can't get it right.
I know there is some easy way to do this.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You recurse on the list and each time pass as first parameter the result of the subtraction:

```
f2 :: Num a => a -> [a] -> a
f2 x [] = x
f2 x (y:ys) = f2 (x - y) ys
```

but here it is simpler to first [**`sum :: Num a => [a] -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:sum) up the elements and subtract these from `x`:

```
f2 :: Num a => a -> [a] -> a
f2 x ys = x - sum ys
```